# AXIS2 Client doesn't work in Websphere

Tags: java, websphere, apache-axis

I deployed the Application which contains an Axis2 Client [1.7.3] to Websphere App Server. But it throws java.lang.InstantiationError: org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBDataSource when the Axis2 client is trying to request a resource from the remote web service endpoint. 
The cause is from a line of code of generated Java class - the return line:

```
public org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement getOMElement(
        final javax.xml.namespace.QName parentQName,
        final org.apache.axiom.om.OMFactory factory)
        throws org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException {
        return factory.createOMElement(new org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBDataSource(
                this, MY_QNAME));
}
```

`factory.createOMElement` is from axiom-api-1.2.19.jar.

Part of my pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-kernel</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-adb</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
                    <artifactId>axiom-dom</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-transport-http</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-transport-local</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
                    <artifactId>axiom-dom</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>axis2-saaj</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

It can work in Tomcat 7 but not Websphere! So I guess part of Websphere library has an issue. Does anyone have experience on this?

Comment: Which version of WebSphere Application Server are you using?

Have you seen https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014885208#77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014885349

Comment: Websphere version is  7.0.0.39

Answer (score 0):

Axis2 1.6.1 is compatible with WebSphere 7.x to 8

- First of all, find axis2 1.6.1 and extract. Then, open archive.

[image: Open archive 7-Zip or WinZip]

- Update the axis2.xml with the following attribute from false to true

[image]

- Update the file in the axis2_1_6_2\WEB-INF \conf  folder
- Navigate to Websphere Admin Console.
- Remove old-axis2 application and directory. - Not required for first installation.
- Install updated war file axis2_1_6_2.war (**Updated Axis2.xml must be in the war file), do not start.
- Complete installation, and navigate Enterprise Applications, click axis2_1_6_2.war.
- Click on Class Loading and update detection, select *Classes loaded with local class loader first (parent last)* and click apply
- Save directly to the master configuration.
- In Enterprise Applications, click manage modules.
- Click on the Module Name Hyperlink Apache-Axis2
- From the drop down Class Loader Order --> Select Classes loaded with local class loader first (parent first) and click apply
- Save directly to master configuration and click OK
  Again, save directly to master configuration
- Select the war file and Click Start, Application started successfully message should be displayed

Links

- Admin Console -- http://host:9080/your-context-root/axis2-admin/

> Username : admin
>
> Password : axis2

- Test WSDL --
  http://host:9080/your-context-root/services/Version?getVersion